# Mockito Junit Test - “Wanted but not invoked; However there were other interactions with this mock” error

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito, completable-future

I have to runnable function in Completable Future with timeout. The runnable function should be invoked only when the original method takes more than the given timeout. The unit keeps giving=
Wanted but not invoked: However, there were exactly 3 interactions with this mock.

All I am trying to do is, I am trying to add timeout for a method execution (getResponseWithTimeoutFunction(itemRequest)) and if the method takes more time, then terminate it and publish count(to understand the timed out response rate) as metric.

```java
@Test
public void testTimeoutFunction() throws Exception {
    Response response = getResponseForTest(); 
    when(requestAdapter.transform(itemRequest)).thenReturn(Request);

    when(dataProvider
        .provide(any(Request.class)))
        .thenAnswer((Answer<Response>) invocation -> {
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
            return response;
        });

    processor = spy(getProcessor());

    when(itemRequest.getRequestContext()).thenReturn(itemRequestContext);
    when(itemRequestContext.getMetadata()).thenReturn(requestContextMetadata);

    List<Item> output = processor.getItemist(ITEM_ID, itemRequest);

    assertTrue(output.isEmpty());
    verify(processor, times(1)).processRequest(Request);
    verify(processor, times(1)).responseTimedOutCount();
}
```

This is method which I am testing for:

```
public class Process {

    @VisibleForTesting
    void  responseTimedOutCount() {
    //log metrics
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Response> getResponseAsync(final ScheduledExecutorService delayer,
                                                                             final ItemRequest itemRequest) {
        return timeoutWithTimeoutFunction(delayer, EXECUTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getResponseWithTimeoutFunction(itemRequest), executorService),
                Response.emptyResponse(), () -> responseTimedOutCount());
    }


    private Response getResponseWithTimeoutFunction(final ItemRequest itemRequest) {
        //do something and return response
    }

   public List<Item> getItemList(final String id, final ItemRequest itemRequest) throws Exception {

        final ScheduledExecutorService delayer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Response response;
        if(validateItemId(id){
            try {
                response = getResponseAsync(delayer, itemRequest).get();
            } catch (final Throwable t) {
                response = Response.emptyResponse();
            } finally {
                delayer.shutdown();
            }
            return transform(response, id).getItems(); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
   }
```

And the timeout function use =

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> timeoutWithTimeoutFunction(final ScheduledExecutorService es,
                                                                      final long timeout,
                                                                      final TimeUnit unit,
                                                                      final CompletableFuture<T> f,
                                                                      final T defaultValue,
                                                                      final Runnable r) {
        final Runnable timeoutFunction = () -> {
            boolean timedOut = f.complete(defaultValue);
            if (timedOut && r != null) {
                r.run();
            }
        };

        es.schedule(timeoutFunction, timeout, unit);
        return f;
    }
```

Exception from Junit :

```
   Wanted but not invoked: process.responseTimedOutCount(); -> at processTest.testTimeoutFunction(processTest.java:377) 
   However, there were exactly 3 interactions with this mock: 
   process.getItemList( ITEM_ID, itemRequest ); -> at processTest.testTimeoutFunction(processTest.java:373) 
   process.validateItemId( ITEM_ID ); -> at process.getItemList(process.java:133) 
   process.processRequest( request ); -> at process.getResponseWithTimeoutFunction(process.java:170)
```

Comment: Thread.sleep is always a bad sign in a test. How can you be sure that the timing is exactly as expected?

Comment: Thats the problem. I want to test whether my timeout function is getting used properly as expected.

Comment: If hope you don't mind my asking: Why do use a seperate `ScheduledExecutorService` for your timeout handling here, when you could have simply used a `get(timeout, TimeUnit)` on the `CompletableFuture` instead? The only reason I could see is that `responseTimedOutCount` is not supposed to run on a `main` Thread.

Comment: @second Sorry wasn't aware of that. Can you let me know breifly ?

Comment: Check the [`javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) here. I know that multithreading is quite difficult to get right, so it might be that I am missing something.

Comment: I have read this [`tutorial`](http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html) which uses a delayer to make the code non blocking, however in that case you can't really use the `get` method before you know that `isDone() == true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test timeouts you probably want to mock the call you want the timeout tested for. Relative to the duration of the test it should take forever.

```java
when(dataProvider
    .provide(any(Request.class)))
    .thenAnswer((Answer<Response>) invocation -> {
        Thread.sleep(FOREVER);
        return response;
    });
```

The verify should have a timeout for threading handling. When the timeout is long, you probably should make sure it is configurable to allow a fast test. Something like `verify(mock, timeout(LONGER_THAN_REAL_TIMEOUT)).someCall()`

Make sure to put a timeout on the total test duration to make sure that current or future failures will not slow down your builds.

Comment: FOREVER = 1000000 something like this ?

Comment: I think that what happening because this test is successful in IntelliJ but not during build

Comment: Sure. But if your test is taking anywhere near that long the test is not correctly working. It should fail.

Comment: So, it means that the process is still running and the thread is not terminating ?

Comment: Updated answer to clarify what should be happening

Comment: I am confused. Sorry if it is naive question. Just trying to learn. My code is structured such that it terminated the call which is taking longer than expected and return a default response in such cases. Also, in such cases it should call the method to publish timeout counter. In this, I am testing for timeout counter calls.

Comment: Mocking is easy to confuse people. Please don’t apologize. It’s a good question. Let me try another way. The mock fakes behavior. The way I suggested is to make the test fail always if there is no timeout handling in the production code. The verify waits until the timeout handling code should have been triggered.

Comment: Got it!! So I added this (along with sleep(1000))= 
        verify(processor, timeout(EXECUTION_TIMEOUT)).processRequest(request);
        verify(processor, times(1)). responseTimedOutCount();

Answer (score 0):

For testing asynchronous invocation, you can use:

```
verify(processor, timeout(1000)).processRequest(request);
```

Comment: But this doesn't test in case of timeouts whether the timeout runnable is getting called or not.